# Maven created Spring web project, but only worked if I deployed its war to Tomcat, and Failed when startup in Eclipse

Tags: spring, maven, junit

I am using spring version  4.1.1.RELEASE with junit version 4.11

I created a Maven with type "maven-archetype-webapp"

Before using junit I put spring-servlet.xml within **webapp/WEB-INF/**. This config works well for Tomcat web container, but Junit cannot refer to this context file because junit's awareness of classpath does not include **webapp/WEB-INF/**.

In order for junit to be able to read the context configuration for spring, I had to put spring's servlet config file at: src/main/resources/config/spring-servlet.xml . Maven will copy this file into **/target//WEB-INF/classes/config/spring-servlet.xml**

In order for this config to work for both JUnit and Tomcat web container , I have to made below modification

**For Junit:**

1> Using Annotation to inform junit about the location of file "spring-servlet.xml"

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:config/spring-servlet.xml" })
public class AnotherTest { ... }
```

**For Tomcat deployment:**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:config/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And things work well for both junit and tomcat deployment.

But from some sources, they said that using "classpath:" would cause confuse about context in some cases (*I don't know which cases*?)

And they suggest we should use below config (namely option2) instead , to avoid using "**classpath:**"

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/config/spring-servlet.xml</param-value> <!-- this config does not use classpath -->
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

With option2 , junit works fine. But running this web project within eclipse would cause FileNotFoundException at the startup time of tomcat because tomcat container **does not see** spring-servlet.xml . Of course I had executed Maven clean & build and ensure that war had been created, I also inspect and see */target//WEB-INF/classes/config/spring-servlet.xml* had been created, Java classes had been compiled, before I execute Maven to start Tomcat.

I found out that, if I copy war file created by Maven, and manually deploy this war into Tomcat then everything work fine.

I doubt that, Maven with Eclipse some how, does not generate WEB-INF/classes/config/spring-servlet.xml properly at the time Maven start Tomcat. At least, I think Maven and Eclipse does not simply using what had been built (i.e project's java class and other resources) to run/deploy with Tomcat.

Is there anyway that I can use the config at option2 above to develop within Eclipse to start Tomcat, and to execute Junit properly?

Or is there any other better way (e.g another directory) to store and config file *spring-servlet.xml* , please explain.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many ways to achieve and here is one of the way which I follow to avoid this type of situations.

I hope the same custom directory structure given by maven is followed.

```
Project
    Module
        src
            main
                Java
                resources
                webapp
            test
                Java
                resources
```

Here are couple of options that we do.

- Accessing the context XML file using `classpath*:`

  - for the test cases in `@ContextConfiguration` which will be access from `main/resources`
  - for the reference in web.xml, context file will be in `main/resources`
- Writing a separate context file for the junit tests

*But from some sources, they said that using "classpath:" would cause confuse about context in some cases (I don't know which cases?)*

confusing the context ? Seriously ? 
Most of the cases, using classpath* will give access to all the files in the execution. Here might be the case where name is same for multiple jars, though I haven't encountered that any point of time.

`Another context file for Junit under test/resources`

This enables the flexibility of making changes to the environment that we use for testing.
For instance

- mocking beans
- Configuring derby database for mock scenarios

Accessing the generated *classes* is not preferable method even though internal access will happen.

And I believe here, there is nothing to do with the version of the spring/junit. Its all about accessing the context file from different perspectives.

Comment: My project structure is just as you provided.

I had also tried "Another context file for Junit under test/resources" as you mentioned above and it works.

 But I concern about keeping synchronization between 2 <servletName>-servlet.xml file. One file is /WEB-INF/<servletName>-servlet.xml, and another file in src/resources/config/<servletName>-servlet.xml, especially when a multilocation teams work on multi-modules.

Comment: By the way, is there any other sources mentioned about having 2 files <servletName>-servlet.xml is a good practice?

Another question is: In case, we want to keep just 1 file src/resources/config/<servletName>-servlet.xml for both JUnit and Tomcat's Servlet Container then what should we do if we do not use "classpath:"?

Comment: Why do we need two files under two different locations when both the contents are alike ?

Comment: Is this what you mentioned "Another context file for Junit under test/resources" ?

Comment: `One file is /WEB-INF/<servletName>-servlet.xml, and another file in src/resources/config/<servletName>-servlet.xml,` this is entirely different ! When you have a context file under `main\resources`, my answer says to create under `test\resources` to maintain the mocking beans if required. and this is no way related to create a document under `/WEB-INF`. When its the same file, why do we need two files ?

Comment: I stil feel vagor about your ideas
- Do you have any tutorial or example code that practical to your technique as "create under test\resources " to maintain the mocking beans?

Comment: By the way, it is the bean I want to test, why would I create mocking beans?

Comment: Another question: I did put my config file (i.e <servletName>-servlet.xml) at src/main/resources/config/<servletName>-servlet.xml.
That's why this web app cannot be started within Eclipse, and that's the problem. It can only be started if I deployed its war into Tomcat manually

Comment: As you know Unit testing always depends on mocking beans. Its not always about the class that you want to test. Creating test beans is one of the way before `@InjectMocks` is introduced. When Integration testing comes to account, the database has always to deal with in-memory db, if you have one such "environment Independent testing" architecture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105337/discussion-between-vinayveluri-and-datnt).

Comment: Vinay, thank you for your information, but the question is not answered.